# Safari disrespecting margins

Tags: html, css, safari

I have experienced inconsistent CSS behaviour with Safari on OS X.

At times margins are not being respected on page load, requiring a window resize or refresh to fix.

We have a list of table elements with things inside. I was however able to reproduce the issue without the content (please see the JSFiddle). I'm experiencing the issue using Safari version 9.0.1 on OS X El Capitan.

http://jsfiddle.net/p0w8fbdm/

HTML:

```
<ul class="table-container">
    <li class="row-item"></li>
    <li class="row-item"></li>
    <li class="row-item"></li>
    <li class="row-item"></li>
    <li class="row-item"></li>
    <li class="row-item"></li>
    <li class="row-item"></li>
    <li class="row-item"></li>
    <li class="row-item"></li>
    <li class="row-item"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.table-container {
    display: block;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    padding: 10px;
}

.table-container:after {
   clear: both;
   content: "";
   display: table;
}

.table-container > .row-item {
    background-color: #FFF;
    list-style-position: inside;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;    
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
    width: 48%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 0.71429em;
}

.table-container > .row-item:nth-child(2n) {
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change `display: table` for `.table-container > .row-item` into `display: table-cell`.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, I could even make them `display: block`.However, what I don't understand is why Safari begins to behave inconsistently when trying to accomplish this layout using `display: table`. A note: This fiddle is only a cut-down snippet - The `row-item` div's on my site has other items inside with `display: table-cell` applied to them. You may be aware in this case the parent div must have `display: table`